# How to store an array of 2 char arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I want to have an array of arrays that store 2 items, so would this be the best way to do it?

```
char array[5][2]= {{"data1","1"},
                {"data2","2"},
                {"data3","3"},
                {"data4","4"},
                {"data5","5"}};
```

and how would I store something in "data2","2" for example?

Comment: I think it should be `char array[5][2][6] = ...` or `const char *array[5][2]`.

Comment: @mch sorry, too fast to read...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it a 2d `char*` array

```
char *array[5][2]= {{"data1","1"},
                   {"data2","2"},
                   {"data3","3"},
                   {"data4","4"},
                   {"data5","5"}};
```

And then to change the string data, you could just access the individual components as such (editing `{"data2","2"}`):

```
array[1][0] = "words", array[1][1] = "a";
```

Basically, when you use the first set of square brackets `array[1]`, that's accessing the row `{"data2","2"}`, and then using the second set of square brackets, you're accessing the components inside of the row. So, `array[1][0]` is `"data2"` initially, and `array[1][1]` is `"2"` initially. Just like `array[2][0]` would be `"data3"` and `array[2][1]` would be `"3"`.

Answer (score 1):

A 2D char array won't work here, but an array of struct would suit your need:

```
    struct string_pairs
    {
        char str1[10];
        char str2[10];
    } array[] = {{"data1","x"},
                {"data2","x"},
                {"data3","x"},
                {"data4","x"},
                {"data5","x"}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Array of `char`

```
char arr1[6] = "data1";               // 1D array
```

Array of arrays of `char`

```
char arr2[2][6] = { {"data1"},        // 2D array
                    {"1"}      };
```

Array of arrays of arrays of `char`

```
char arr3[5][2][6] = {{"data1","1"},  // 3D array
                      {"data2","2"},
                      {"data3","3"},
                      {"data4","4"},
                      {"data5","5"}};
```

Assign `"dataX","X"` to second element of array as

```
strcpy(arr[1][0], "dataX");
strcpy(arr[1][1], "X");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a typical task for structs.
In my fiew, this should work:

```
struct strings  // definition of a struct calld strings
{
char[] a;
char[] b;
}

struct strings arrayofstrings[n];  // instancing an array of structs

arrayofstrings[i].a = {"data"};  // reference to the element "a" of the i-part of the array
arrayofstrings[i].b = {"1"};
```

you can creat n instances of structs "strings"

Comment: `char[] a;` will not compile. Do you mean `char a[10];`? `arrayofstrings[i].a = {"data"};` also won't work.

Comment: you are right, the "{" "}" aren't necessary, but why does the compiler need a constant for char[] a?